# LISP recursion using car/cdr

Tags: recursion, lisp

I need help in an assignment using LISP. I need to create a program (two different functions) that can take an output such as ((PRO)(LAN)) and convert it to NATO (PapaRomeoOscar LimaAlfaNovember). As well as be able to convert NATO to english, ((PapaRomeoOscar) (LimaAlfaNovember)) to pro lan.

It needs to use recursion, no loops, and not have any variables. My professor went over LISP for a week and showed us basic programs. I am clueless about this one.

My thinking, is that I need to cons the lists together, and then take the car of the list and check it using if statemnents:

```
(if (= car(L1 L2) "i")
  (format -t “India ”)
(format -t ""))
```

And then recursively take the cdr of the list passing it recursively. Any help at all will be very helpful. I have been looking online to find example code and can't find anything similiar to it. I've gone to her office hours and she says we should know how to do it based on her notes, which are simple factorial functions.

Then for converting the NATO to english, I think you need to cons the list, take the car of the list. Then take the car of the car and use an if statement similiar to the one above. Then take the cdr and recursively pass it back. I'm not sure how the code would look so I need lots of help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "((PRO)(LAN))"? Is that supposed to be a string? A data structure?

Comment: All the instructions say, is it takes an input as a phrase and displays its NATO code as a string

Comment: Are the instructions online somewhere?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YN_51T6SICMn6rU1b_IIRfVFwPJ3Mf8D

Comment: Please read your assignment carefully.  The input is a list of lists of symbols named by a single character in the first case, and a list of lists of symbols named by a NATO character name in the second.  The output is a string in both cases.

Comment: Wow; a Lisp prof that knows that Lisp actually **has** loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
(if (= car(L1 L2) "i")
  (format -t “India ”)
(format -t ""))
```

Some problems in this snippet:

- `(= car (L1 L2) "i")` reads as: apply function `=` to three arguments: the variable named `car`, `(L1 L2)` and `"i"`, where `(L1 L2)` is the application of function `L1` to argument `L2`. If you want to take the `car` of a list, use `(car list)`.
- `=` works only on numbers: passing anything else, like a string, will not work as expected. Use `string=` when comparing strings, or better, don't use strings at this step. See for example `assoc`, `symbol-name` and `string-capitalize`.
- The `-t` in `(format -t "")` is not correct. If you want to write into a fresh string, use `nil`. If you want to output to the standard output, use `t`.
- `(format -t “India“)`: notice you are using `“` quotes, which are not the ones you should use in your programs (`"`). Besides, you are always printing a space, which is a problem if you want to join different words together, as explained in the assignment (e.g. `"AlfaBeta"`).

Comment: adding the space only between words and not after them and not after the whole sentence is another non-trivial complication not easily done with straight "car/cdr" recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing Lisp with C syntax. Don't do that. Don't even think you can use algol experience, eg. you know C of python,  with assimilating since while C, C++, perl and python is in the same famil of Alhol languages, Lisp isn't. It took me some time to find the `for` loop back in the days. Over a year actually.

I think perhaps the input should be `'((p r o) (l a n))` and not `'((pro)(lan))`. These change what you need quite a lot.

Did you understand the input/output in you assignment? Since you are printing to stdout and not returning, does that mean you should read the input from stdin instead of parameters in to the function? Eg. imagine this function that reverses a list:

```
(defun my-reverse (list)
  (labels ((helper (list acc)
              (if (endp list)
                  acc
                  (helper (cdr list) (cons (car list) acc)))))
    (helper list '())))

(my-reverse '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (3 2 1)
```

This does not read or print anything, except the REPL does print the returned value from the function call.

You need to divide your problem into simpler ones. So imagine I do it for one symbol. eg. `(to-nato 'p) ; ==> papa` then you have something you can use in a recursive function that translatea structure.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

## First, the algorithm

It seems you understand the principle of it. Iterating recursively through a list is a very common idiom is Lisp: you take a list, do something with its `FIRST`, then call yourself with the `REST` (`CAR`/`CDR` are legacy names, I prefer using more meaningful ones when possible).

```cl
(defun print-every (objects)
  (print (first objects))
  (print-every (rest objects)))
```

As you are recursing, the only other thing you need is to terminate somewhere, usually when the list given to you is the empty list (beware, `(rest '())` ⇒ `()`, so if a function just recurses on the rest of the list, it will never stop).

```cl
(defun print-every (objects)
  (when objects
    (print (first objects))
    (print-every (rest objects))))
```

If you need to collect a result from the whole operation, the usual way to do it is using an **accumulator**, a function argument that *accumulates* that result.

```cl
(defun add-every (numbers &optional sum)
  (if numbers
      (add-every (rest numbers (+ (first numbers) sum))
      sum))
```

## Second, the syntax

Like with any other programming language, you need to be extra careful and not use something from language A in language B.

An argument starting with a dash like `-t` is something you'll see in bash, not in Lisp. `(format t "foo")` will print `foo` (and a line break).

In Lisp, `(foo bar(1 2) 3)` will **NOT** give arguments `1` and `2` to the function `bar`. If you want that, your code needs to be `(foo (bar 1 2) 3)`.

Also, in Lisp, what separate expressions are parentheses and spaces. So `'(pro)` is a list containing **ONE** symbol, but `'(p r o)` is a list containing **THREE** symbols.